# PowerShell Active Directory Login Script Auto-Build

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I've created an active directory account creation script using powershell 4.

My Boss has stated there's a new policy where we have to build a login script per user, is there a way to do this where it'll build the .bat file and map the drives that we specify within the script?

I know there's a way to build .txt files, but not sure about .bat.

**What I need**
Select Drives That The user Needs Access To
I need it to build a .bat file, mapping the drives previously specified.
Then move it to the login script folder on the DC, mapped to S

Comment: What's stopping you from going ahead and attempting to do this? Stack Overflow is not a script-writing consultancy

Comment: Maybe you should start managing these things with proper GPOs instead of infinite login-scripts.. But if you really want to do it, you can build .bat files the same as you would .txt files..
.bat files are text-based, its not like they need some special magic encoding

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about doing it. I'm learning powershell, as i go @MathiasR.Jessen do you have any good resources? Im not sure where to look

Comment: @Paxz I've suggested the GPO Method, however the customer (A Trust within the NHS in the UK) wants to use login-scripts online.

Comment: @JamesTimms well that's terrifying. TBH, I'd suggest googling "learn powershell" - there's a wealth of resources and books on this topic. Additionally I'd suggest you ask your manager for relevant training - most of the Microsoft Official Course ware around Windows Server from 2012 and up will contain some level of guidance around leveraging PowerShell for administrative purposes as well

Comment: Feel free to come back and ask specific technical questions related to coding in PowerShell, it's just that Stack Overflow really isn't a very well-fitting format for what you're seeking atm

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I mean for a beginner, i've got a pretty good script built, that performs everything extremely well. I just don't really know how to do this

Comment: @JamesTimms then you should really be showing off your script, sharing what you've attempted and what you're having exact issues with. Currently the question is more a request of "do it for me"

Comment: @Matthew I've discovered, i'm not very good at laying stuff like this out haha

Comment: Just a little note on the side;) : https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520948/additional-outputs-based-on-group-memberships

Is this a better question @Paxz

Comment: @JamesTimms yeah! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Future reference to anybody who wants to do this.

I've managed to resolve it myself after some playing around.

```
$NewName = $SAMAccountName
$extension = ".bat"
$FileName = "$SAMAccountName$extension"
$ScriptDrive = "\\IPREMOVED\scripts"

Write-Output "
BAT CONTENTS" `n`n|FT -AutoSize >>LoginScript.txt

Get-ChildItem LoginScript.txt | Rename-Item -NewName $FileName 
Move-Item -Path ".\$FileName" -Destination $ScriptDrive
```