# Additional Outputs Based On Group Memberships

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I hope you all are having a great day. I apologize in advance if this is a terrible attempt at a question, I'm not very good at this.

---

**Introduction**

So First of all, I'd like to introduce what I am actually creating.

I work for a MSP, and I've been tasked with creating a User Management Powershell Script to be used for one of our Customers so that we can easily manage users and automate a lot of our user creation processes.

I have run into an issue, which is why I am asking for help

---

**The Issue**

Our customer is insisting on using Login Scripts over GPO for mapping drives for users. I have added a login script builder to the script, however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to specify which drives actually need adding to the login script.

---

**How Drive Mappings Are Managed**

The way drive mappings are managed at our customer's network, is based on Job Role + Active Directory Groups. They request on an E-Form which drives need to be mapped, and we then look through the Active Directory to see which group has permissions to access the requested drives. We then add these groups.

---

**What I Need Help With**

I need to find a way for the groups to be specified by the technician creating the user, this then needs to translate into one of the selected drive mappings, which then writes to the login script. I have attempted it myself, however I Just cannot figure out a way to do this for different drives.

---

**Current Code**

*Note, This may not all be in Order, There May Be Code In-Between on The Actual Script. This Is Just Relevant Code*

```
[String]$path= ".\LoginScript.txt"
$NewName = $SAMAccountName
$extension = ".bat"
$FileName = "$SAMAccountName$extension"
$ScriptDrive = "\\IPREMOVED\scripts"

$group = "zz Everyone"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty Name

$Drive1 = If ($Members -contains $SAMAccountName) {
                                                   Write-Output "Net Use N: "\\FILE0\Senior Duty Nurses""
                                                   }
                                                   Else {
                                                         Write-Output "Net Use N: "\\FILE0\Senior Duty Nurses""
                                                         }
Write-Output "NET TIME \\FILE0 /SET /Y

$Drive1

@echo off
REM ------------------------------- 
REM -- LANDesk v8.6.1 Installation -- 
REM ------------------------------- 
%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk\iDeploy.exe /F=%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk" `n`n|FT -AutoSize >>LoginScript.txt

Get-ChildItem LoginScript.txt | Rename-Item -NewName $FileName 
Move-Item -Path ".\$FileName" -Destination $ScriptDrive
```

---

If you need any more code, just ask and I will post it in an edit below this line. Thank you in advance :)

---

**EDIT**
I've managed to get this working with the following layout

```
# Params
$NewName = $SAMAccountName
$extension = ".bat"
$FileName = "$SAMAccountName$extension"
$ScriptDrive = "\\IPREMOVED\scripts"
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $SAMAccountName | select -expandproperty name

# Define All Groups and Drives
$infosec = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain info sec'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use I: "\\FILE0\Info-Security " "
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }

$mgmtboard = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain mgt board'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use : "\\FILE0\Board Committee Papers" "
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }

$anaesthetics = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain anaesthetics'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use : "\\FILE0\anaesthetics" "
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }

$adverseir = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain adverse ir'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use : "\\FILE0\adverse incident reports" "
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }

$breastcancersecs = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain breast secs'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use : "\\FILE0\breast cancer secs" "
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }

$bookwise = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain bookwise'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use : "\\FILE0\bookwise" "
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }

$patientassessment = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain assessment'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use : "\\FILE0\patient assessment" "
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }

$clinicaleducation = IF ($Groups -contains 'domain clinical educ'){
                                        Write-Output "Net Use : "\\FILE0\clinical education" " -NoTypeInformation
                                        }
                                        Else {
                                              Write-Output " "
                                              }


# Creates The GroupMap
$GroupMap = $infeosec,$mgmtboard,$anaesthetics,$adverseir,$breastcancersecs,$bookwise,$patientassessment,$clinicaleducation

# Create The Drive Param
$Drives = $GroupMap


Write-Output "NET TIME \\FILE0 /SET /Y

$Drives

@echo off
REM ------------------------------- 
REM -- LANDesk v8.6.1 Installation -- 
REM ------------------------------- 
%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk\iDeploy.exe /F=%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk" `n`n|FT -AutoSize >>LoginScript.txt

Get-ChildItem LoginScript.txt | Rename-Item -NewName $FileName 
Move-Item -Path ".\$FileName" -Destination $ScriptDrive
```

However, within the login script. It shows the following.

```
NET TIME \\FILE0 /SET /Y

             System.Object[]

@echo off
REM ------------------------------- 
REM -- LANDesk v8.6.1 Installation -- 
REM ------------------------------- 
%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk\iDeploy.exe /F=%LogonServer%\Netlogon\LANDesk
```

Why is it showing System.Object[]? Can this be removed?

Comment: Even though this is a programming related question, I think you'd have more luck on [sf] as questions on professional server/networking-related infrastructure administration are covered there. I would bet the sysadmins there will have come across this situation before and be able to offer suitable advice :) Voting to move this question there.

Comment: Am I able to move the question, or do I have to rewrite it @JamesC.

Comment: I don't think you can move it yourself, you would have to select 'flag' (under your questions tags) and ask a moderator to move it for you.

Comment: Are you planning on generating a logon script per user? That's going to have to be individually assigned by group policy *anyway*, isn't it? Push back on this: "*Our customer is insisting on using Login Scripts over GPO*" if possible; if you're the MSP, they get to decide what they need ("mapped drives that work") and you should get to decide how you make that happen and make it work. Anyway, you have one logon script, likely PowerShell, and it's the same for everyone, and it gets the user's groups and then does `"if ($myGroupNames -contains 'driveZusers') { map drive z }"` over and over..

Comment: And then it doesn't have to go in this user setup script. This only covers - take a parameter for groups to put the new user in, and then `Add-AdGroupMember` the user account into them.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler We're their MSP, however it's a very large contract (The NHS in the UK) and they pulled the plug on their last MSP for not doing things how they like them. Login scripts is the way they do the auto-mapping. So what I have done, is created the script to build the bat file (still haven't finished the mappings obviously), move it to the loginscript server then it adds it to the user's active directory script path. 

The only thing I have left to do is this Drive Mapping per group.

If I need to, I can add the whole User Creation to the post for you to see?

Comment: I have added to the code above, since it has hit a wall.